# Which version of sql server 2008 will have profiler on MSDN?

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

Is there another download besides sql server 2008 developer that will have profiler in it? I just want a local developer installation not a full blown server version.

It has to have at least SP1 on it also.

I am having issues with sql server 2008 developer 64-bit on my windows7 64-bit o/s.

Answer (score 4):

Developer is equivalent to Enterprise Edition, FYI.

Profiler is included in Standard, Enterprise (and hence Evaluation) and Developer editions.  You need to install one of these, but you needn't install the core engine - you only need the client tools to get SQL profiler.

Alternatively, you can use system stored procedures to create your traces (see here for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx)

Comment: Generally, yes.  Developer Edition is normally what you use.  It contains ALL of the features of Enterprise Edition, under a not-for-production-use license.